# Got problems in installing GEOS for basemap in windows 10

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap, geos

I know that this problem has been asked before, and hope that the administrators will not regard this question as a duplicate for it is a bit different. I am using `Python 3.6, Windows 10 system with 64 bit`. I've successfully installed pip and have used pip to install a bunch of packages (including numpy, matplotlib, mpl_toolkits and so on). But when I install the basemap and run the `from mpl_toolkits.basemap install Basemap`, an error occurs saying that `there is no module named "mpl_toolkits.basemap`.
I go to the document of basemap and it says that `GEOS` of 3.1.1 is required. And when I run the `pip install geos`, what I get is only `geos-0.2.1`.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/cuv9Q.jpg

(so inconvenient to upload pictures)

Is their any alternatives to download GEOS for the basemap installation? I know there's a way for Linux to install, but it does not seem to work on Windows.

Comment: What is `from mpl_toolkits.basemap install Basemap`? That line does not make any sense. `GEOS` is included in the Basemap binaries for windows, so there shouldn't be any need to install it separately.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered similar problem and finally managed installing `basemap` via Anaconda in my windows7 environment. I have tried following `basemap` official installation instruction in Unix Shell and `pip install xxx.whl` methods, and both failed. I think the possible reasons can be some file not compatible with Windows or not up to date.

Basemap installation via Anaconda:
1. Install Anaconda following official instruction.
2. Install `basemap` using Anaconda Prompt (be sure to use Anaconda Prompt), run `conda install -c anaconda-forge basemap`. This may prompt anaconda upgrade, accept it. Then anaconda will install the package and the prerequisites, including latest `geos`, for you automatically.
3. Run with your favorite IDE. I run jupyter notebook from ANACONDA PROMPT, this is important. Since I have two versions of python, and basemap can not be loaded if I initiate jupyter notebook from cmd.
Have to mention that I did install PROJ4 in advance, so I am not sure if Anaconda will install it for you or not if you don't have one. Basemap official installation instruction: https://matplotlib.org/basemap/users/installing.html, you can also find PROJ4 instruction linkage there.
Hope this could help.